# MacOS and F6 causing the actual window to loose focus

Tags: macos

I have a problem with F6 key in MacOS (Lion). I have set the normal behavior for all function keys and disabled every shortcut using functional keys in Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. Still I cannot use F6 key because it causes the actual window to loose focus. I have searched all the settings in MacOS shortcuts and there is none enabled that uses F6, nevertheless there is none that uses just this very key whatsoever.
I am already desperate because I cannot use Midnight Commander properly. Is there any way to determine what is using this key and disable it?

Comment: THis should be MOVED to apple.stackexchenge.com instead of being closed.

Comment: @sorin Agreed. I voted to re-open. Let's get it opened and moved. This is very helpful information, even if it doesn't belong here.

Comment: @mbm29414 questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated, so there is no use in reopening this to get it moved.

Comment: The answer made it possible for me to use Eclipse's debugger (F6 used to step) over Parallels, so in my case it was helpful programming information ;-)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I have discovered that Parallels had registered F6 as global shortcut and thus disabling it for everything else. Once I removed the shortcut, everything works just fine.

To remove the global shortcut in Parallels Desktop 12, from a running virtual machine on the top VM menu go to `Devices` > `Keyboard` > `Customize…` > `OS X System Shortcuts` and uncheck `Show and hide Parallels Desktop`.

You can also get to this setting from the Control Center window (no need to have a VM running) by clicking the gear icon from any VM and then going to `Mouse & Keyboard` > `Open Shortcut Preferences…` > `OS X System Shortcuts`.

Comment: When, it seems that if you disable it in application preferences it will be reassigned when Parallels starts again, even if the settings shows it as disabled.

Comment: @Krumelur It's in Parallels Preferences->Shortcuts->System Shortcuts.  Then untick "Show and hide Parallels Desktop".

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful!

Comment: @PhilipKearns this is great, saved me a lot of frustration, thanks.

Comment: Odd that they chose this since so many people use Parallels just to run Visual Studio and F6 is `Build` in VS

Comment: Thank you ! I've been accidentally hitting F6 for years and loosing window focus... only now i know why lol

Comment: Thanks - I had no clue that it was Parallels.